# $(".k-grid-header").html() is not supporting in IE9 and IE8 browsers

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
       $(".k-grid-header").html('<table style="table-layout:fixed;"><tr style="color:#ee9f05"><th></th><th></th><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;border-right:2px solid #ee9f05;color:#ee9f05;font-weight:bold"><a style="text-align:center;color:#ee9f05;font-weight:bold" href="DetailsPage.html">Xbox</a></td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;border-right:2px solid #ee9f05;font-weight:bold"><u>Surface</u></td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;border-right:2px solid #ee9f05;font-weight:bold"><u>Keyboard</u></td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold"><u>Mouse</u></td></tr><tr style="color:#ee9f05;text-align:center;"><td></td><td></td><td style="color:#ee9f05;text-align:center;font-weight:bold">Actual</td><td style="color:#ee9f05;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;border-right:2px solid #ee9f05;">Var</td><td style="color:#ee9f05;text-align:center;font-weight:bold">Actual</td><td style="color:#ee9f05;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;border-right:2px solid #ee9f05;">Var</td><td style="color:#ee9f05;text-align:center;font-weight:bold">Actual</td><td style="color:#ee9f05;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;border-right:2px solid #ee9f05;">Var</td><td style="color:#ee9f05;text-align:center;font-weight:bold">Actual</td><td style="color:#ee9f05;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">Var</td></tr></table>');
```

This my kendo-grid header template , This template is working fine in IE 10 browser but come to Other browsers like IE 9 IE 8 and so on.. it's not supporting in those browsers What am I doing wrong?

[image: In browsers IE9 and IE8][image: In browser IE10 in Windows 8 System]

Comment: It looks fine. There maybe some other issue. Post some more code.

Comment: Hi muthu..just it is browser support issue i have problem with this piece of code only .. other than this my code is working fine with out custom header

Comment: Check here http://fiddle.jshell.net/DfB7B/show/, its works on IE 8

Comment: Excellent as individual it's working but when i am using this in Kendo ui Grid again and again problem is reproving..u have any idea about kendo ui grid

Comment: I've tried it with IE8 (inside a grid) and  and Kendo UI revision 2.1114 and 3.1315 and works with both. Which version of KendoUI are you using? Do you have some CSS that might interfere and the problem might be with your CSS definition (try removing your own styles)?